# Metrics on Euclidean spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I vaguely remember a theorem that says that any two metrics on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent in some sense, but probably not in the sense of metric equivalence: two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are said to be metrically equivalent if there are positive numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that

$c_1 d_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le c_2 d_1(x,y)$, $\forall$ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Can somebody confirm which kind of equivalence there might be?

Thanks.

Comment: I personally don't know of any definition of equivelance between metrics other than the one you stated.

Comment: @GitGud: There are many. For example, you might consider two metrics equivalent if they induce the same topology, or the same uniform structure.

Comment: @GitGud Here's another: we call the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on the same space $X$ equivalent if for every $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ there exist $r_1,r_2 > 0$ such that $N_{r_1}^{(1)}(x) \subset N_r^{(2)}(x)$ and $N_{r_2}^{(2)}(x) \subset N_r^{(1)}(x)$, where $N_\alpha^{(i)}(x)$ is the $\alpha$-ball in the $d_i$ metric.

Comment: @proximal: That's the same thing as inducing the same topology.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Ah. Indeed it is. (I learned this definition in real analysis class, so I hadn't thought about it in terms of inducing topologies.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct statement is that any two metrics **derived from norms** on $\Bbb{R}^n$ are equivalent in this sense. There are plenty of metrics that are not equivalent: for example, the discrete metric is not equivalent to the standard Euclidean metric, but this is because the discrete metric doesn't come from a norm.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I just thought of another question: is it true that any two norms on a Euclidean space are equivalent in the above sense?